# Accessing SCM (Git) variables on a Jenkins Pipeline job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Here's my pipeline code:

```
node ('master') {
    git url: "$GIT_REPO_URL", branch: "$GIT_BRANCH"
    echo env.GIT_COMMIT
    echo env.GIT_BRANCH
    echo env.GIT_REVISION
}
```

The build results looks like:

```
Started by user anonymous
[Pipeline] Allocate node : Start
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
[Pipeline] node {
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://acme/scm/app.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://acme/scm/app.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://acme/scm/app.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision fb455725db1b768ff63e627a087d2771099af7c4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f fb455725db1b768ff63e627a087d2771099af7c4 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master fb455725db1b768ff63e627a087d2771099af7c4
 > git rev-list fb455725db1b768ff63e627a087d2771099af7c4 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] } //node
[Pipeline] Allocate node : End
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The env variables env.GIT_COMMIT, env.GIT_BRANCH are not populated. Are those values available in another variables?

Comment: Whats the point of marking duplicate without a link to the original???
Thats totally not cool and useful to anyone!!!!!

Answer (score 25):

Here is an example of how you can get `GIT_COMMIT` (ref: [Jenkins GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/960779c/pipeline-examples/gitcommit/gitcommit.groovy)):

```
// These should all be performed at the point where you've
// checked out your sources on the agent. A 'git' executable
// must be available.
// Most typical, if you're not cloning into a sub directory
shortCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'").trim()
```

You can extend it to expose `GIT_BRANCH` as well.  This script is from the workflow examples git repo managed by cloudbees. Maybe you can send a pull request if you add capability to retrieve `GIT_BRANCH` variable.

Comment: You can't actually extend this to get GIT_BRANCH since jenkins checks out in a detached head state.

Comment: You can use a shorter command that returns the same result `git describe --always`.

Comment: please put the answer inline, rather than as a hyplerlink.  Ta.