# How to clone a directory from a remote repo in a Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a large repo in GitHub Enterprise and need to clone a sub-directory from it on my Jenkins build server and just build that sub-directory. I am using a pipeline script and have this right now:

```
node {
    stage ('checkout') {
        git url: 'git@github.devops.mycompany.local:Org/MyLargeRepo.git'
    }
}
```

What I want is to clone from `github.devops.mycompany.local:Org/MyLargeRepo/path/to/subproject`

I know I probably need to use sparse checkouts, but can't seem to work out how to configure that in a Jenkins pipeline script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline), and not [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline)

With the latter, you can [use the syntax seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340315/6309), based on the [`hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPaths` class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/SparseCheckoutPaths.java) from The Jenkins Git Plugin:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/branchName']],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [
        [$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths',  sparseCheckoutPaths:[[$class:'SparseCheckoutPath', path:'folderName/']]]
                ],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'someID',
    url: 'git@link.git']]])
```

Don't forget the [`.git/info/sparse-checkout` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274043/6309)