# Can I augment scm in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It's taken me ages to understand what `checkout scm` really means in Jenkinsfile (checkout is a function and scm is a default global variable by the way).

Now that I've understood it, I want to augment `scm` for example to increase the timeout for a particular checkout or to set `sparseCheckoutPaths`. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293334/sparsecheckout-in-jenkinsfile-pipeline/43293547 just found a similar question with an answer

Comment: Yes I'd seen that question @minas but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Git, `checkout scm` is basically equivalent to :

```
checkout([
     $class: 'GitSCM',
     branches: scm.branches,
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
     extensions: scm.extensions,
     userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
])
```

If you want to add sparse checkout to the existing scm, what you would do is something like:

```
checkout([
     $class: 'GitSCM',
     branches: scm.branches,
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
     extensions: scm.extensions + [$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths',  sparseCheckoutPaths:[[$class:'SparseCheckoutPath', path:'path/to/file.xml']]],
     userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
])
```

Even better, you can define a **custom step**, `sparseCheckout` in a shared library.

```
def call(scm, files) {
    if (scm.class.simpleName == 'GitSCM') {
        def filesAsPaths = files.collect {
            [path: it]
        }

        return checkout([$class                           : 'GitSCM',
                         branches                         : scm.branches,
                         doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
                         extensions                       : scm.extensions +
                                 [[$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths', sparseCheckoutPaths: filesAsPaths]],
                         submoduleCfg                     : scm.submoduleCfg,
                         userRemoteConfigs                : scm.userRemoteConfigs
        ])
    } else {
        // fallback to checkout everything by default
        return checkout(scm)
    }
}
```

Then you call it with:

```
sparseCheckout(scm, ['path/to/file.xml'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely customize the `checkout scm` command to add more flexibility. Check out this link for all of the options - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

Timeouts:

> `$class: CheckoutOption timeout::::`
>   Specify a timeout (in minutes) for checkout. 
>   This option overrides the default timeout of 10 minutes. 
>   You can change the global git timeout via the property org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut (see JENKINS-11286). Note that property should be set on both master and slave to have effect (see JENKINS-22547).
>   Type: int

SparseCheckoutPaths:

> `$class: SparseCheckoutPaths`
>   Specify the paths that you'd like to sparse checkout. This may be used for saving space (Think about a reference repository). Be sure to use a recent version of Git, at least above 1.7.10

Comment: But how do I augment the existing `scm` object with those values?

Comment: @mjaggard - do you mind posting your current jenkinsfile? it'll be easier to understand/explain.

Comment: I have a line that reads `checkout scm` where `scm` is a particular repo, branch, etc. but I don't know what repo at time of writing the Jenkinsfile. I want to use sparse checkout paths.

Comment: @mjaggard - I believe this should comment should have the information you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340315/5107771

Comment: It doesn't list how to change an existing variable (`scm`) with the values.

Comment: @mjaggard try replacing `checkout scm` with the snippet in the link I gave you in the previous comment (of course insert the correct values for your case).