# Is it possible to build only some directories within a github project with jenkins?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

There are directories representing backend, frontend, and AI in the GitHub project, and I want to connect only the backend directory with Jenkins. What should I do?

Comment: So just build only what you want in jenkins? I mean, __you're__ the one writing the Jenkinsfile, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a [sparse checkout in your Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340315/6309) in order to checkout only the folder you want.

That way, the rest of your build process only see the right folder.