# How to checkout specific folder from remote git repo using jenkins pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use jenkins pipeline to download a folder from git repo.I am using

```
                git branch: 'abc', credentialsId: 'abc', url: 'https://github-abc.com/platform-org/abc.git'
```

But this checks out entire repo. I need only 1 folder from this repo. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Even if you use the full SCM class in the code it would still reference the entire repo. If it is not possible with git's intrinsic functionality, then it would not be possible with the wrapped code either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SparseCheckout in Jenkinsfile pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293334/sparsecheckout-in-jenkinsfile-pipeline)